# Websites using RTMP don't allow proxy

Tags: transparent-proxy

Real Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP) is a flash based protocol used for streaming, chatting etc. I need to use RTMP based website at my university for some reason but the connection fails as my network uses a proxy. I have tried Tor and Proxifier but had no luck.

If anybody could guide me, I'd appreciate that.

P.S: I read somewhere that RTMP uses port 1935, and my best guess is that port is blocked due to proxy. How should I unblock that port?

Comment: I think they (University guys) filters ports above 1024 or they just open some certain ports, like 80 53 443 and filter others

Comment: So, what do you suggest? Is there a way out?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your university's RTMP server *via Tor*? You university's RTMP server may only allow connections from within the University, and not from the outside.

Comment: It is not my university's RTMP, it is a global website. It works quite well when I access it from home.